# Sublime Text 3 missing top tabs bar

Tags: sublimetext3

I recently moved to a new hardware and had to port all my settings from my old macbook to the new one.
On sublime text 3 I had two lines of tabs on my old laptop and only one line in the new one.
Top tabs level was with the directories that I have opened (like different projects have their own tabs), while the second line of tabs had each file I had opened from this directory (very useful). On the old macbook the top line with tabs appears when I open a second directory (so two tabs for 2 projects). On the new one just a new window is open for each directory I open.

[New Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVCjq.png)

[Old Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWgiD.png)

Currently all folders I open are opened in their own window.
I tried the solution that many people provided on the internet and added a custom setting for the "open_files_in_new_window" to false, but this does not work.
Both macbooks are running Sublime Text 3.1.1, Build 3176

Does anyone have an idea how to have the top level tabs back.

Comment: You need to change the `Prefer tabs when opening documents` setting in the `Dock`  section of the system settings. Also it doesn't work if you use the Adaptive theme, so you need to use some other theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not SublimeText3 option but MacOSX option.
System Preferences -> Dock -> Prefer tabs when opening documents: Always

Comment: Are you using the default theme ?

Comment: Did you try this ?
System Preferences -> Dock -> Prefer tabs when opening documents: Always

Comment: Sorry for the spam. Just to let you know that I tried on a macbook with ST 3 and it's working fine with the setting above. Change it and then create a new projet, you'll get the result you want.